# Insert sql query not inserting row in db

Tags: java, jdbc

I am  inserting a new row in db, there is no exception in the console. But the row is not inserted into the table.

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String query = "INSERT INTO `test`.`student`(Name,City,Country)VALUES(?,?,?);";
        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,city);
        ps.setString(3,country);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
```

Comment: What does `executeUpdate` return?

Comment: Please  remove the `;` from your sql query and try again.

Comment: hwo do you prepare the connection? Do other queries using this connection work?

Comment: @voidmain try putting commit. I saw comment from dxdy below but not all jvm has autocomit = true. Its a good practice to commit your work when you think it is done.

Answer (score 0):

- No need of casting the PreparedStatement again in connecting the query. It should be like

  ```
  Connection conn = getDBConnection();
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
  ```
- Remove the ; from the query inside the doublequotes
- Prefer concatenation operator ( + sign) while using single quotes inside double quoted strings in the query

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that I have tested and working fine. Compare it with your code to know what you are doing wrong.

```
public void insertRowToDB(int staffID, String first_name, String last_name, int department_ID) {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = DatabaseConnection.getconnection();
        if (!dbConnection.isClosed()) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO staff (staffID,first_name,last_name,department_ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, staffID);
            statement.setString(2, first_name);
            statement.setString(3, last_name);
            statement.setInt(4, department_ID);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (dbConnection!=null) {
                if (!dbConnection.isClosed()) {
                    dbConnection.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

A priori view of your code, there is no the `commit` statement.

You need to perform this statement right before the `ps.close()` line.

Best regards!

Comment: By default, JDBC automatically commits the statements.

Comment: @dxdy not all jvm does that. Also it can be set true or false at connection level.

Comment: The Oracle docs say "By default a Connection object is in auto-commit mode, which means that it automatically commits changes after executing each statement. If auto-commit mode has been disabled, the method commit must be called explicitly in order to commit changes; otherwise, database changes will not be saved." I would assume that if OP chose a JDBC driver that handles things differently, they would do so by choice and be aware of it. The same applies for the manual setting, I would assume that if OP had gone to the effort of manually disabling it, they would be aware of it.